# When and how to be more loose when checking for equivalence of two objects?

Tags: python

Code in Python as example.

For instance I have an emoji class with following attributes and dunder method:

```
class Emoji:
  def __init__(self, name: str, animated: bool = False, id: Optional[int] = None):
    self.animated: bool = animated
    self.name: str = name
    self.url: str = url
    self.id: int = id

  def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if self.is_unicode_emoji():
        return isinstance(other, Emoji) and self.name == other.name

    if isinstance(other, Emoji):
        return self.id == other.id
    return False

  def __ne__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    return not self.__eq__(other)

  def is_unicode_emoji(self) -> bool:
    return self.id is None
```

So Unicode Emojis like , , , , etc. all don't have an `Emoji.id`. However a user can upload a custom Emoji and each have a unique `id`.

The dunder method `__eq__()` was implemented and it checks if the two `Emoji` instances are the exact same.
If the Emoji uses Unicode Emojis it checks for the equivalence of the Unicode Emojis. If they are custom Emojis it checks if they are the same id.

I often see people using the code thinking the `Emoji` returns a string and thus are directly checking the `Emoji` instance with a string. This will of course fail.
Does it make sense to be more loose in the definition of equivalence and extend it with:

```
if isinstance(other, str):  
  return self.name == other
```

or is that a bad practice? This would check an `Emoji` instance against a string.

My personal issue is `emoji == ""` would then return `True` but `"" == emoji` would return `False` (with `emoji` being an instance of `Emoji`). That's not intuitive and I wouldn't know how to fix that. Is there a fix?

I hope I'm in the correct stackexchange. Stackoverflow seems to be wrong since it is more about debugging errors and they tend to close questions on best practice, recommendations and so on.

Comment: This is the perfect community to answer this question, in my opinion. It is a good, solid conceptual question with a well-defined problem.

Comment: “`"" == emoji` would return `False`” – have you actually tested that theory? The expression `a == b` is not blindly translated to `a.__eq__(b)`, instead [Python uses more complicated dispatch rules for comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__). This works because comparison methods should return `NotImplemented` if the types don't match, so that `b.__eq__(a)` can be tried as a fallback.

Comment: @amon I don't see in the linked doc that the fallback `b.__eq__(a)` would be used. Rather it also says `There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods`. I have also tested.

Comment: @TinNguyen That paragraph is not written clearly, but it attempts to explain that there are no reverse-comparison methods, e.g. `__reverse_eq__(a, b)` for `b == a`. Instead, the `__eq__` method is used regardless of the position of the argument. That paragraph explains how it's determined whether a's or b's method has priority. I'm not sure what you have tested, because in all my tests `string == emoji` clearly works: https://ideone.com/D5vVyG

Comment: @amon thanks!! I should have used anminimal example to test >.<

Answer (score 2):

Python, and other loosely-typed languages, have a disadvantage in this situation. The code `emoji == ""` will execute. A syntax-aware editor for Python will not flag that piece of code as a syntax error. For a moment, consider this same class in a strongly-typed language. In C#, for instance, the comparison operator would be defined as an explicit operator-overload:

```csharp
public class Emoji
{
    ...

    public static bool operator ==(Emoji left, Emoji right)
    {
        // compare left and right
    }
}
```

The signature of the `==` operator overload requires an `Emoji` on both sides of the comparison. This naturally leads to a syntax error when comparing `emoji == ""` because the "left" object is an Emoji, but the right object is a System.String. A strongly-typed language won't encounter this problem at all. If you wanted to compare an Emoji to a string, you will need to add an explicit operator overload: `bool operator==(Emoji left, string right)`.

Loosely-typed languages must check types at runtime when the function signatures cannot be annotated with types. There does not appear to be anything you can do to catch this problem in Python prior to runtime.

Instead, consider throwing an error if the "righthand" object is a string. This will result in a runtime error, but at least the error would be easier to debug than a mysterious `emoji == ""` returning `false` when the developer and code reviewers expect it to return `true`.

Comment: Thanks. I think throwing an error would be easiest for debugging and also make most sense 

Comment: Note that C# has similar issues such as Python if we look past the operator overloading aspect and into the `Object.Equals()` method which cannot be overloaded for specific types. This is a core problem in all object-oriented languages that want to allow equality comparisons between any two objects – it necessarily needs runtime type information or comparable dynamic features. Specifically in Python, throwing an exception within `__eq__` would violate that method's contract – it should `return NotImplemented` instead.